# Browse product images from server ?

Tags: product, product-images, image-upload

I need to know if there is a way to browse product images from server and not upload them. I have several products with the same images and i am uploading the same image several time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having trouble with duplicate product images you could try

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/image-clean.html

Made my life easier :)

---

Sorry, the question was not clear to me, I know that when you upload an image with exactly the same name it overrides it so that won't be an issue. A quick Google for your issue brought me here: http://www.pixelpaul.net/magento-share-images-on-more-products/, I haven't tested it / checked if its best practise but you could give it a shot.

Comment: Images are used by product, but i want to use the same image for several products without re uploading them. If there is a way to browse files from server like in html editor ti will be perfect.

Comment: Ok, but what are you planning to do by browsing the server for the images, image references are saved in the database so basicly you need to refer to the image there. For browsing them, you could always setup an ftp and connect to it with your editor. Same will work with sshfs etc...

Comment: The idea is simple, i want to take images from server not upload them. i dont know how i can achieve this.

Comment: See my edited answer